# Security error occured with http request and Universal Apps

Tags: c#, http-headers, httprequest, win-universal-app

I want to create my own remote app for a domotic project which uses Domoticz, with Universal Apps (Win 10) in C#. 
I use Basic-Auth and it works perfectly with WinForm or WPF project, I can connect and get (in this case) or set values in the server :

```
    private async void request()
    {
        string uri = @"http://username:password@192.168.1.1:8080/json.htm?type=devices&filter=all&used=true&order=Name";
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string token = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username:password"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", token);

        string body = await client.GetStringAsync(uri);
    }
```

However, this sample doesn't work with Universal Apps (Win 10), I get this exception :

```
An error occurred while sending the request.
```

When I look at InnerException I see that :

```
A security problem occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800C000E)
```

Is there a solution to connect my app to my domotic server like WinForms apps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not include the user name and password in the URI ([RFC 3986 3.2.1 User Information](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.1)).

Instead, use a `HttpClientHandler` and a `NetworkCredential` to pass the user info, i.e.:

```
Uri uri = new Uri(
    "http://192.168.1.1:8080/json.htm?type=devices&filter=all&used=true&order=Name");

HttpClientHandler handler = new HttpClientHandler();

handler.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
    "username",
    "password");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);

await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove @ from the URI -

```
see string uri = @"http://username:password192.168.1.1:8080/json.htm?type=devices&filter=all&used=true&order=Name";
```